# Unable to get Silverstripe betterbuttons to work

Tags: silverstripe

Unable to get the 'betterbuttons' module to show up:

https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons

This seems like a nice addition that should 'just work' with any ModelAdmin in the CMS.  Do I need to configure something additionally in my site _config.php to configure it?

Comment: yes, it should 'just work', and it does for me. no you do not need any additional configuration. Please specify what version of SS you are using and more details on how you installed the betterbuttons module

Comment: SS 3.1.  Directory name should just be '/betterbuttons' yes?

Comment: appreciate a bit late, but yes /betterbuttons  - did you get it to work? it doesn't display any extra buttons for me either.  I think it used to...